# Class not displayed in GraphDB

Tags: rdf, owl, graphdb

I have the following class:

```
:Foo rdf:type owl:Class ;
           rdfs:subClassOf [ rdf:type owl:Restriction ;
                             owl:onProperty :hasId ;
                             owl:someValuesFrom rdfs:Literal
                           ] .
```

Strangely, that does not appear in the Class hierarchy tab of Ontotext's GraphDB.

Is there any specific reason?

Comment: Are you talking about the visualization as shown [here](http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/exploring-data.html#) ? Don't know how they compute it, but I'm pretty sure in the end all the visualization stuff is more or less based on SPARQL queries (or some advanced internal stuff). Maybe because your class is a subclass of a complex class expression which isn't shown in the diagram? Just a guess though. You could try some other complex class expression as super class to check if that's always the case.

Comment: You could also then add another atomic superclass in addition to the complex one, if this works I'm sure we found the reason and you should contact the support

Comment: Hello again @AKSW! Well if I insert that class plus a common-defined class (A a owl:Class) then I see just A in the diagram.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any specific reason?

From `graphdb-framework-graph-explore-8.7.0.jar/dataviz-queries/getRdfClassHierarchy.sparql`:

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX sesame: <http://www.openrdf.org/schema/sesame#>

SELECT ?parent ?class ?count  {
    ?class sesame:directSubClassOf ?parent .
    FILTER (isURI(?parent) && isURI(?class)
        && !strstarts(str(?parent), "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#")
        && !strstarts(str(?parent), "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#")
        && !strstarts(str(?parent), "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#")
    ).
    {
        SELECT ?class (COUNT(*) as ?count) {
            ?s a ?class
        } GROUP BY ?class
    }
} ORDER BY DESC (?count)
```

Note `isURI(?parent)`, whereas `[…]` [is a](https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#grammar-production-blankNodePropertyList) blank node.

Comment: great, that's what I expected because this simplifies the visualization. Indeed, one could argue that all classes should be shown, but I guess there are always limitations when working with complex class expressions. Nevertheless, the docs could add a statement that clarifies this point. Cheers.